# Using a ResourceDicitonary in a Windows Phone 8.1 Portable Class Library

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library, resourcedictionary

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Portable Class Library with a `ResourceDictionary` in `Themes/Generic.xaml`
Now, I want to declare styles there and use them in other Controls I have, in my `ResourceDictionary` I have something like:

```
<Style x:Key="myCustomStyle" TargetType="ProgressBar">
    {...}
</Style>
```

And in my Control, something like:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="dictionary">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
{...}
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Style="{StaticResource myCustomStyle}" />
```

But this does not work, but if I have the Style in my Control, it works fine, it's the `ResourceDictionary` reference that's not working.
How can I make it work?

Comment: I guess this `Style="{StaticResource myCustomStyle"` is a typo, it's missing a `}`

Comment: Yup, already corrected.